# Recursively deleting all files of one type using Ant

Tags: java, ant, delete-file

In an ant build script, how can I delete all `*.java` files in one directory and its subdirectory?

Comment: why? this sounds very dangerous...

Comment: there is an example in the docs: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html

Comment: @Travis Webb - One use case would be to delete auto-generated code when cleaning up after a build.

Comment: @user534009 - One bit of clarification: do you want to delete all .java files recursively, or ONLY in the CURRENT and IMMEDIATE subdirectory of the base directory (i.e. not more than one directory deep)? My answer has assumed a full recursive delete under the specified base directory.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's slightly unclear how deep in the directory tree you would like to delete the `.java` files. I'll provide ways to do both.

**Full recursive delete**

Recursively deletes all `.java` files anywhere under the provided target directory.

```
<delete>
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/path/to/target/directory" includes="**/*.java"/>
</delete>
```

**Only within the target directory and its immediate child directories**

Deletes `.java` files in the specified target directory, and in any directories that are immediate children of the target directory, but no further.

```
<delete>
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/path/to/target/directory" includes="*.java,*/*.java"/>
</delete>
```

For additional options, have a look at the [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html) for the delete task.

**Be careful** - If you put the wrong directory in for your target directory, you might delete things you don't want to. Consider making the paths to your target dir relative to the build file, or to `${basedir}`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<delete>
<fileset dir="." includes="**/*.java"/>
</delete>
```

The above [delete](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html) task deletes all files with the extension .java from the current directory and any subdirectories.

Answer (score -2):

```
<delete>    
    <filename name="**/*.java"/>
</delete>
```

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html

Comment: -1: In Ant 1.8, this results in a DEPRECATED warning and a failed build, with the message: `At least one of the file or dir attributes, or a nested resource collection, must be set.` `<filename>` needs to be inside of a `<fileset>` for the XML to be valid.